# Did the US create ISIS?

Tags: politics, terrorism

I recently came across this post on my facebook frontpage:

http://www.redflagnews.com/headlines-2015/alert-media-ignores-report-showing-pentagon-created-isis

Now the post links to a multitude of other sites making various other but similar claims, they all go along the line of "Pentagon funding ISIS/Qaeda" or at least includes this claim. Now I understand the US is a huge arms dealer and has been for decades. We all know of the guns they sold to Iraq and various other countries during the cold war which has come back to bite us all in the ass http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_support_for_Iraq_during_the_Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_war So I'm not interested in whether or not the US sold/gave guns or other resources that inadvertently ended up in the possession of either extremist groups. My question is about whether or not they deliberately created ISIS in an effort to destabilise Syria. This is a claim made in the first source and many links from it.

> It stated this was “exactly what the supporting powers to the opposition want, in order to isolate the Syrian regime, which is considered the strategic depth of the Shia expansion.”
>
> As noted above, the “supporting powers” are the West, led by the United States, and the Gulf Emirates and Turkey.

...

> "Given this, and the fact that the US-coalition continuously aided the sectarian Syrian opposition knowing full well that this would then lead to an “Islamic State”..."

The actual title of the article is even more provocative (surprises! :D)

> ALERT -- Media Ignores Report Showing Pentagon Created ISIS

So my question is **did the pentagon *deliberately with intent* 'create' ISIS with the intention being it overthrows or damages the Syrian government**.

Comment: I can't answer this entire question (although I'd say "Red Flag News" is not a good source for this kind of claim) but many of the weapons that we gave the Iraqi military have fallen into the hands of ISIS because the Iraqi military is incompetent and let a lot of equipment get captured. That being said, many weapons the US uses require really expensive and restricted ammunition (i.e. Javelin Missiles) that ISIS won't be able to get their hands on once they use up their current captured amount.

Comment: @RobertRose I'd agree it's not a good source but it itself links to multiple other sites and you can find this kind of stuff everywhere if you look. But Googling it scared me and made me worry about our future as an intelligent race so I've opted to force others through it. Also yes, the question isn't 'are there american supplied arms in the possession of ISIS etc.' rather 'are there arms the US deliberately supplied to ISIS etc.'

Comment: Can you restrict this to a single verifiable claim? ISIS or Al-Qaeda? In what ways were they funded or supported, according to the claim?

Comment: @Sklivvz Ok, I'll limit it to ISIS considering they're prominence today and I'll limit it to just creation/inception.

Comment: What does the claim say exactly?

Comment: @Sklivvz **ALERT -- Media Ignores Report Showing Pentagon Created ISIS.** But I'll focus on the "Pentagon Created ISIS" bit

Comment: If the US really created ISIS, do you REALLY think the that US government would leave evidence behind :)...

Comment: Of course.  ISIS is something bad, therefore the US must have created it!

Comment: @RobertRose And how many of those weapons were handed over in exchange for a bribe rather than even needing to be captured?

Comment: Claim eems a bit iffy, when you consider that ISIS is the continuation of something that started a thousand years before the US even existed.

Comment: Claiming that the US "created" ISIS is vague. What specific actions are they alleged to have taken in bringing about its creation? It would be possible to consider whether those actions took place. Whether the  intention behind those actions was, in fact, to create ISIS, is a question of motivations that we cannot answer objectively.